# Win32 ToolTip disappears never to re-appear with Commctl 6

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm creating a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760250(VS.85).aspx) window and adding tools to it using the flags
TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS. (c++, win32)

I have a manifest file such that my program uses the new WindowsXP themes
(comctrl32 version 6).

When I hover over a registered tool, the tip appears.
Good.
When I click the mouse, the tip disappears.
Ok.
However, moving away from the tool and back
again does not make the tip re-appear. I need to hover over a different tool
and then come back to my tool to get the tip to come back.

When I remove my manifest file (to use the older non-XP comctrl32), the
problem goes away.

After doing some experimentation, I discovered the following differences
between ToolTips in Comctl32 version 5 (old) and Comctl32 version 6 (new):

- New TTF_TRANSPARENT ToolTips (when used In-Place) actually return
  HTCLIENT from WM_NCITTEST if a mouse button is down, thus getting
  WM_LBUTTONDOWN and stealing focus for a moment before vanishing. This causes
  the application's border to flash.
- Old TTF_TRANSPARENT ToolTips always return HTTRANSPARENT from WM_NCHITTEST,
  and thus never get WM_LBUTTONDOWN themselves and never steal focus. (This seems to be just aesthetic, but may impact the next point...)
- New ToolTips seem not to get WM_TIMER events after a mouse-click, and
  only resume getting (a bunch of) timer events after being de-activated and
  re-activated. Thus, they do not re-display their tip window after a mouse
  click and release.
- Old ToolTips get a WM_TIMER message as soon as the mouse is moved again
  after click/release, so they are ready to re-display their tip.

Thus, as a comctl32 workaround, I had to:

- subclass the TOOLTIPS_CLASS window and always return HTTRANSPARENT from
  WM_NCHITTEST if the tool asked for transparency.
- avoid using TTF_SUBCLASS and rather process the mouse messages myself so
  I could de-activate/re-activate upon receiving WM_xBUTTONUP.

I assume that the change in internal behavior was to accommodate the new "clickable" features in ToolTips like hyperlinks, but the hover behavior appears to be thus broken.

Does anyone know of a better solution than my subclass workaround? Am I missing some other point?

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one who has hit compatablity issues with tooltips between these DLLS.

I too have had **nothing but trouble** with the new tooltips in the themable common controls. We have already been monkeying with mouse messages and active/deactivating the tips before adding the manifest and theming our application - so it sounds like what your doing isn't too crazy.

We're still living with problems with TTN_NEEDTEXT messages being send constantly as the mouse moves (not just when hovering), positioning problems with large tips (maybe not something new), and odd unicode messages being sent instead of the ANSI versions (which I plan to post as a question at some point).

Comment: I have a similar problem with `tooltip` control. My problem seems simple, yet nobody offered solution for it. I offered a bounty but got 1 answer that is not helpful for me. I ask you if you could look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238449/tooltip-is-never-shown-again-after-i-click-on-the-button-rephrased-to-reflect) and tell me if you have ever encountered and solved such problem. I apologize for disturbing you like this, usually I don't ask for help this way but I am desperate. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff, I looked the the question. Too much time has passed since I've done win32 for me to help with something so specific, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but this sounds like a really "hard" problem (in the sense that all real-world) problems are really hard. I bet the underlying problem is something to do with the setting of the focus. Windows that manually do that are evil and generally suffer from all manner of bugs.