# Tooltip is never shown again after I click on the button

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip

I want to create a simple `tooltip` that will pop when user hovers over a `button`.

To do that I have studied [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Everything works fine when I **first** time hover over the `button`, but after that `tooltip` **never** shows up again ( **I have checked return values for `HWND` of the `tooltip` and for `SendMessage( ..., TTM_ADDTOOL, ... )` and there were no errors** ).

I have tried to find the solution online, but have failed. The only resource I have found that **might** be useful is [this tutorial](http://www.interq.or.jp/chubu/r6/masm32/tute/tute027.html) but it suggests to **subclass** the control in order to relay mouse messages to the `tooltip` control-I **will not** accept this type of solution because I believe **what I ask for is the basic functionality** `tooltip` control provides.

---

### EDITED ON JANUARY 21st 2014:

Following instructions from the [link member *Stuart* suggested*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/757905ce-7a32-4b1a-a73b-a2992556b242/initcommoncontrolsex-returns-false) I was able to partially solve the problem. Now `tooltip` is shown after clicking on the main window's client area and then hovering back over the button.

However, **after I click on the button** `tooltip` never shows up again .

Browsing through Internet, I have found [this example](http://winapi.foosyerdoos.org.uk/code/commoncntrls/htm/createtooltips.php) and after adding these directives:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
    language='*'\"")

#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")
```

the problem seemed to disappear. Now I was able to click on a button, hover over edit control and edit control's `tooltip` would appear.

However, after clicking on a button, then clicking on the client area of the main window, **and then hovering** over the button again its `tooltip` did not show!

Then I have continued to search over the Internet and have found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20729/Tool-Tip-Class) on *CodeProject* and it does exactly what I need.

So I have started to analyze **the source code** of the first example and this article. I was unable to see the difference. However, **appearances were different**! It seems that the article **did not** use `Visual Styles`, and taking into the consideration `MSDN article` member *Stuart* mentioned, I have started to suspect that this **might be the manifest issue**.

So I have tried to compile all the programs without the first `pragma comment` submitted above, but in my test application ( the one created as `default Win32 project` ) `InitCommonControlsEx` failed, in the example program I have got error `Failed to save the updated manifest to the file ".\Debug\foosyerdoos tooltip.exe.embed.manifest". The parameter is incorrect.`, and the article application failed to create `tooltip` controls.

After creating the fresh blank project, and after copying the code from the first example-only this time without `pragma comment`-`SendMessage` failed to add both `tooltip`s.

So, without first `pragma comment` submitted above, I can not use `tooltip` controls or so it seems.

### END OF EDIT

---

Here are the instruction for creating the minimal example that illustrates the problem:

1. Create `default Win32 project` in `MS Visual Studio`;
2. Add the bellow `WM_CREATE` handler:

   ```
   case WM_CREATE:
       {
           HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"Button", L"test me!", 
               WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
               50, 150, 150, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)8003, hInst, 0 );

           HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx( NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
               WS_POPUP | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,
               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
               hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL );

           // Associate the tooltip with the tool.
           TOOLINFO toolInfo = { 0 };
           toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
           toolInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
           toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
           toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hButton;
           toolInfo.lpszText = L"test 1";

           SendMessage( hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo );
       }
       return 0L;
   ```
3. Compile and run-`tooltip` should show on **first** hover, but **never** again.

I work on `Windows XP`, using `MS Visual Studio Express 2008`.

`Visual Styles` are enabled, I have linked `comctl32.lib` and have initiated `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX` structure's `dwICC` member with `ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_TAB_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES`.

---

### EDIT ( January 31st, 2014 ) :

After testing this very same code snippet on my laptop, which has `Windows 7` I can confirm that everything works fine. This is the problem with my `Windows XP` I guess...

### END OF EDIT:

---

My question is really simple:

How to adjust my code so the `tooltip` is shown **every time** user hovers over the `button`?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. I did two things differently. 1. I used VS 2005, and 2. I compiled the project as C code.

Comment: @Stuart: Did you try it on `Windows XP` ?

Comment: Yes, I am running Windows XP. I ran into a problem with calling InitCommonControlsEx (the call would fail). I eventually solved that problem after reading the comments at the end of this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/757905ce-7a32-4b1a-a73b-a2992556b242/initcommoncontrolsex-returns-false

Comment: @Stuart: OK, I have moved my `pragma comment` to `stdafx.h` and placed it bellow `#include<windows.h>` and `include<commctrl.h>`. My next problem happens when I click the button-`tooltip` never appears again. I wish it to appear **anytime** when user hovers over the button. Do you have any idea how to achieve this? Thank you for your help and for partially solving my problem. Best regards.

Comment: When I checked I realized that I had the same problem you describe, once I click the tooltip doesn't appear again. I tried a few things and  came up with two different ways to make this work. When the button is clicked either: 1. Remove the button from the tooltip and then add it again, or 2. Destroy the tooltip (with DestroyWindow) and then re-recreate it. I don't really like either solution but they work.

Answer (score 2):

You are chasing the wrong problem, this behavior is by design for tooltips.  The exact rules it uses are not documented anywhere I know of and I never personally found any need to reverse-engineer it so I can only tell you what I've seen.

The bigger idea behind the feature is that it avoids wearing out the user with info that he already knows.  Tooltips were very much designed to be *tips*, just a sliver of information that isn't crucial to proper operation of the program.  It appears to be implemented by keeping track of a tip for a tool already having been displayed and **not** display it again if the tool was used.  Which of course makes a lot of sense, the user doesn't need to be reminded what a tool does after he used it.

There is no message to reset that "the tip was displayed" state.  It will reset when it displays the tip for another tool.  Altering the tip resets it as well.

I'd reiterate that this is something you should **not** try to fix.  The behavior is perfectly sensible.  If it is important anyway then you'll have to take control and display the tip yourself, TTM_ACTIVATE message.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on my laptop with Windows 7 as you are expecting.

Since this is Microsoft's example, I highly doubt that there is a mistake in it.

To follow the advice of Sherlock Holmes: "Once you eliminate the impossible, all what is left, no matter how improbable, is truth." Since code works, then it must be problem with Windows XP, which can be confirmed with the above  follow up comments to your question.

I would check if I have downloaded all automatic updates or would reinstall and try your code again. You could also test your code on other machine running Windows XP to see if your own is the problem.

Good luck.